# Basic Authentication before pulling XML in java

Tags: java, api, authentication

I've just started dealing with an api that is running on https and requires authentication to pull from.   I have no issues pulling up the xml in a browser, but is there some way to authenticate in java before I try to pull the data over?

At present I've just been using simple sax pulls on http xml files and have never had to authenticate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the XML file before parsing it using a connection and

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html

Some examples etc from oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html